# Complete Insert/Update/Delete of Child Entities in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I know it has been asked before, but after long hours of searching and coding I can't get to a working and clean approach. Here is what I have:

```
public class QuestionModel
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    public IList<QuestionChoiceModel> Choices { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionChoiceModel
{
    public int ChoiceID { get; set; }
    public string ChoiceText { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using EF 5 for this ASP.Net MVC application. Generic Repository Pattern and Dependency Injection with Ninject using `InRequestScope()` are in place and work smoothly. These models are mapped to/from entities without a problem.

Adding new Questions to database is straight forward. I set Question property of some QuestionChoice instances, and EF handles the rest.

The problem is about updates. Assume we have a Question in database with 3 QuestionChoices:

```
ChoiceID    QuestionID    ChoiceText
--------    ----------    ----------
1           1             blah blah
2           1             blah blah
3           1             blah blah
```

When edit page of a Question opens (GET: /Questions/Edit/1), I show these 3 choices using a `foreach` in Razor. I've written some JQuery code that adds or deletes required markup for input elements if user wants to. So, the QuestionChoice with ID=1 might be edited on client, ID=2 might be deleted, and a new ID=4 might be added. The form data is bound back to a QuestionModel perfectly when user presses the Save button (POST: /Questions/Edit/1). The model is mapped to a Question entity correctly. That is where the story begins!

Now the Question entity has a collection of QuestionChoices some of which are already in database, some should be added to database, and some should be deleted from database.

I've read many posts like:
[Entity Framework not saving modified children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054798/entity-framework-not-saving-modified-children)

I can handle edits in that dirty way. And also new records by:

```
this._context.Entry(choice).State = EntityState.Added;
```

But I'm looking for a more elegant way. And also handle records that should be deleted. Is there a good approach to handle complete insert/update/delete of child entities in this scenario using EF? Honestly, I expected more from EF.

Answer (score 7):

This is a tough problem. Unfortunately, I cannot offer the solution that you prefer. I do not believe it is possible. EF cannot track changes made to your entities unless they are made within the context that the entities are retrieved - which is impossible in a web environment. The only way for this to be possible would be to retrieve the Question object (within a context) after the POST to /Questions/Edit/1, and to perform a type of "merge" between the POSTed Question, and the Question retrieved from the database. This would include assigning properties on your `QuestionModel` and each `QuestionChoiceModel` retrieved from the database using your POSTed `QuestionModel`. I will say that this wouldn't be great practice either, because you WILL forget to include a property. It will happen.

The best (and easiest) solution I can provide would be to add/edit your `QuestionModel` and `QuestionChoiceModel(s)` using the `.Entry()` method above. You will sacrifice "best practice" here for a solution that will be less error-prone.

```
QuestionModel questionFromDb;
QuestionModel questionFromPost;

QuestionModelChoice[] deletedChoices = questionFromDb.Choices.Where(c => !questionFromPost.Choices.Any(c2 => c2.Id == c.Id));


using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    db.Entry(questionFromPost).State = questionFromPost.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

    foreach(var choice in questionFromPost.Choices)
    {
        db.Entry(choice).State = choice.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
    }

    foreach(var deletedChoice in deletedChoices)
    {
        db.Entry(deletedChoice).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is just proof of concept.**

**Controler** have func **UpdateModel** but it wont work with more complex model which have included child records. Look for **TestUpdate**.

Rule#1: Every Table have PK Id column.

Rule#2: Every FK have to be set.

Rule#3: Cascade delete need to be set. if you want remove related record.

Rule#4: New Record need to have Id = 0 or better will be Null but Id cant be null.

```
public class TestController<T> : Controller where T : class
{
    const string PK = "Id";

    protected Models.Entities con;
    protected System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T> model;
    public TestController()
    {
        con = new Models.Entities();
        model = con.Set<T>();
    }

    // GET: Default
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Result = TempData["Result"];
        TempData["Result"] = null;

        var list = model.ToList();
        return View(list);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult AddEdit(string id)
    {
        int nId = 0;
        int.TryParse(id, out nId);

        var item = model.Find(nId);
        return View(item);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult AddEdit(T item)
    {
        TestUpdate(item);

        con.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Remove(string id)
    {
        int nId = 0;
        int.TryParse(id, out nId);
        if (nId != 0)
        {
            var item = model.Find(nId);
            con.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
            con.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }

    private void TestUpdate(object item)
    {
        var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            object value = prop.GetValue(item);
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsInterface && value != null)
            {
                foreach (var iItem in (System.Collections.IEnumerable)value)
                {
                    TestUpdate(iItem);
                }
            }
        }

        int id = (int)item.GetType().GetProperty(PK).GetValue(item);
        if (id == 0)
        {
            con.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            con.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }

    }

}
```

Here is project https://github.com/mertuarez/AspMVC_EF/

You need to create Controler for model and create view for action.
In case of AddEdit action you have to create editor Template for subtypes.